# Texas Hold'em heads up pre-flop AK vs 89s

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds, probability

According to online calculators:

A♥K♦ (57.91%) vs 7♣8♣ (41.71%)

A♥K♦ (59.42%) vs 8♣9♣ (40.19%)

A♥K♦ (58.59%) vs 9♣T♣ (41.00%)

Why is 8♣9♣ worse odds than the other 2?

I assume it has something to do with potentially dealing TJQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is steals

78
9TJQ steals

89
TJQ steals

9T
JQ steals and they need a T you have covered

When it need less cards to fill in the steal the steal is more common

9T is better than 89 as the T blocks the ace high straight

I am surprised 78 is better than 9T

Comment: why is 78 better than 89?

Comment: @ricka Answered - it need less cards to fill in.

Comment: 9T needs even less cards to fill in than 89, yet it is worse... I am confused.

Comment: @ricka I stated clearly T is a block

Comment: 78 is better than 9T because some of the times where 9T hits a pair of Ts, it's no good because of the straight.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru And from a K block on JQK see other answer

Answer (score 1):

87s

- 654
- 569
- 69T
- 9TJ

98s

- QJT  << this straight doesn't win vs AK
- JT7
- T76
- 765

T9s

- KQJ  < less combos of this, but still plenty will be left
- QJ8
- J87
- 876

Comment: Why did you edit this? You did nothing but put a space behind 87s?